# XMLHttpRequest random fail on readyState and status

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am solving one problem for about 3 hours, searched a lot of topics about it...but I am still stucked.

Want to load the xml file from a server on load (tried also from public folder, same result) and use them for a API similar to google maps (but API is not the problem).

I tried a lot of ways how to write the xml loading via XMLHttpRequest, but always the same thing.

Few times it's ok, then I change some little code and fail, then if I revert changes, it's still failing...
Can't recognize the pattern what could be wrong.

The problem is, the readyState is sometimes 1 and status 0.
Sometimes it's OK and I can go to the body of function.

I am running apache server with php(symfony) and the path to the file is OK (I can see it in browser too. And again ... sometimes it's fine)

Here is my code on the start of js file:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", 'http://localhost/project/src/test.xml', true);
request.responseType = 'document';
request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
request.onload = function () {
  if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      console.log(doc);
      // Some other code (parsing xml)
    }
  }
};
request.send();
```

Maybe some other way of loading needed than via XMLHttpRequest, but dunno how eventually.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Now some idea come to me.Maybe it's because the xml loading is asynchronous? So maybe something like await in c# needed?

Comment: Try [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) approach.

Comment: Usually you would check the `readyState` inside a `readystatechange` event handler. This is because the `readyState` will change from `0` to `4` and you'll want to do something when `readyState` `4` is reached. The `onload` event handler will be called whenever `4` is reached, so checking the `readyState` won't do anything. But where is the `doc` variable defined? And are you checking the `responseText` or `responseXML` properties whenever the `onload` is fired?

Comment: Yes it's asynchronous, but because JavaScript is event driven it's possible to wait for the `load` event to fire before continuing. Though `async / await` is just another way of approaching your code, but won't explain what you're running into.

Comment: Hmm onreadystatechange helps (y) . But I have still a question.. I want to use the data from that body right after the send. And as I can see in debugger, the code under send is called before the body of onreadystatechange is entered, it means I can't use data from that request. How to wait for finished request?

Comment: Or should I only return the responseXML and parse it out of the onreadystatechange ?

Comment: Any data that is received will be available in either the [`responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) or in the [`responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) properties of the `request` instance whenever the `readyState` has reached `4` and the request has been successful. So inside the event handler check for that condition and access the properties mentioned.

Comment: I will try that, thanks